# DropDownList in Bootstrap XS do not open

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ASP application and a problem with a dropdownlist. It will not open on XS mobile devices:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1">
        <!-- Anzahl Zeilen DropDownList -->
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserGridViewRows" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="True"
            CssClass="form-control font-13"
            data-style="btn-primary">
            <asp:ListItem Value="5"> 5 </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="10"> 10 </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="15"> 15 </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="20"> 20 </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="30"> 30 </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="50"> 50 </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 font-13 hidden-xs" style="padding-top: 6px;">
        Zeilen pro Seite
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-5 col-lg-offset-6 col-lg-3">
        <!-- Unit DropDownList -->
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUnitList" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="True"
            CssClass="form-control font-13"
            data-style="btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This works well on LG, MD and SM screensize (Bootstrap). Resize the browser to XS screen size will no longer open the **first** dropdown list. Any idea?!?

Answer (score 1):

Use Bootstrap Dropdown i think it solve your problem.
use `class="dropdown"` with your main div and also assign `class="dropdown-menu"` to your dropdown list item.

For more details study :  http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns